# Hacked Faceboook Profile and Encrypted PGP mail

Tags: encryption, pgp, facebook, kleopatra

Similarly to the issue [Decrypting a PGP Message inside .asc file](https://superuser.com/questions/1777593/decrypting-a-pgp-message-inside-asc-file)
my FaceBook profil has been stolen (unknown e-mail added, set as "main e-mail" for FB, password changed, and my own e-mail removed)

I did the process to have back my profil, unfortunatelly, no telephone linked, so I used a "ID process" to confirm my identity

And later that, FB asked me:

- a) Name
- b) New e-mail for communication
- c) A password

And then, I've received an email (to the adress in "b" above), but encrypted.
Whit 2 files:

- "noname" (a readeble file with this inside: "Content-Description: PGP/MIME Versions Identification Version: 1)
- "encrypted.asc" (with his -----BEGIN PGP MESSAGE----- and -----END PGP MESSAGE-----)

I  wonder if the password (point "c" in the short list above) it is the way to read the email, but I have no instructions and all my attempts have failed. In any case some "private key" is asked.I've used, for my first time, Kleopatra.

Someone told me that maybe is not really "encripted" but just "signed", and this cas a public key will be enought. But I'm lost, and I don't know how to continue.

Have you some idea to help me, please?

Thank you.

Comment: See https://www.cnet.com/tech/computing/how-to-make-facebook-send-you-encrypted-notification-emails/ When that is done start the ID process again.

Comment: Thanks Gantendo.
But  my profile is stolen, so I can't entry to change the setting.
And, these settings doesn't exist in the actual version of FB (I tried on an other account, just to understand, but it doesn't exist)

Comment: https://www.facebook.com/hacked